# Deploying to bare EC2 instances in an ASG?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-auto-scaling

I have a service that needs to run on our own EC2 instances, since it requires some support from the kernel. My previous experience is all with containers in AWS. The application itself is distributed as a single JAR file and I'm looking for advice for how I should automate deployments. The architecture is:

1. An ALB in front of the ASG.
2. EC2 instance running a single Java application.

Any open sockets are open for an hour tops and to not cause any trouble, we have to drain the connections to the EC2 instances before performing an update, so a hard requirement is for the ALB to stop opening new connections for an hour before updating the software. The application is mission critical and ECS has had some issues last year, so I want to minimize the AWS services I depend on. While I could do what I want on my own ECS cluster with custom AMIs, I don't want to do it, since I will run a single instance of the app per host and don't need the extra layer.

**My question**: What is the simplest method to achieve this using CodePipeline? My understanding is that I need to use a CodeDeploy deployment step to push something to bare EC2 instances. How does draining with an ALB work in this case? We're using CloudFormation for the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use codedeploy. You can find tutorial on AWS codedeploy documentation.
Codedeploy deployment lifecycle hooks for EC2.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-server